# assign RGB values in java with nested for function

Tags: java, colors, rgb, pixel, javax.imageio

I have some question, here is my code :

```
int W = img.getWidth();
int H = img.getHeight();
int [][] pixels = new int [W][H];
int [][][] rgb = new int [3][H][W];
for(int i=0;i<W;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<H;j++){
        pixels[i][j] = img.getRGB(i,j);
        Color clr = new Color(pixels[i][j]);
        rgb[0][j][i] = clr.getRed();
        rgb[1][j][i] = clr.getGreen();
        rgb[2][j][i] = clr.getBlue();
    }

/*
 pixels changing process 
 */

//1st for
for(int[] asd : rgb[0])
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(asd));

//2nd for
for(int i=0;i<W;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<H;j++){
        /*Color myColor = new Color (rgb[0][i][j],rgb[1][i][j],rgb[2][i][j]);
        int newrgb = myColor.getRGB();
        img.setRGB(W,H,newrgb);*/
    }
}
```

printing the red values with 1st works normally, but why I can't put that values using 2nd for ?

when I run the code, it issues ByteInterleavedRaster.setDataElements(int, int, Object) line: not available

I want to assign image colors with new values of rgb[0] (red), rgb[1] (green), rgb[2] (blue) that printed by using 1st for. When I expected it could work with 2nd for, it threw an error.

thanks in advance :)

Comment: What does mean "I can't change"? Does it throw error? Does it have different output than you expect? What is expected output and what is real output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change this line `img.setRGB(W,H,newrgb)` to this one `img.setRGB(j,i,newrgb)`.

Comment: I'm using 48x48 dimension image, so i think it doesn't matter with i and j position. it still threw an error although I swapped the i, j @libik

Comment: Thread [main] (Suspended (exception ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException))
owns:BufferedImage(id=32)
ByteInterleavedRaster.setDataElements(int, int, Object) line: not available 
BufferedImage.setRGB(int, int, int) line: not available 
Chapter1.main(String[]) line: 303 -> img.setRGB(W,H,newrgb);

Comment: omg, thats why you HAVE to add the error stacktrace to see on which line it is.

Comment: thank you so much. this is my first time posting here, so I'm so sorry for my mistake. have a nice day. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this looks correct

```
int W = img.getWidth();
int H = img.getHeight();
int [][]   pixels = new int [W][H];
int [][][] rgb    = new int [3][W][H];

for(int i=0; i<W; i++)
    for(int j=0; j<H; j++) {

        pixels[i][j] = img.getRGB(i,j);
        Color clr = new Color(pixels[i][j]);

        rgb[0][i][j] = clr.getRed();
        rgb[1][i][j] = clr.getGreen();
        rgb[2][i][j] = clr.getBlue();
    }

/*
 pixels changing process 
 */

for(int i=0; i<W; i++)
    for(int j=0; j<H; j++){

        Color myColor = new Color (rgb[0][i][j],
                                   rgb[1][i][j],
                                   rgb[2][i][j]);
        int newrgb = myColor.getRGB();

        img.setRGB(i, j, newrgb);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have i,j image. when I use getRGB values, it show j,i array, so I changed it with [0/1/2] [j] [i]

Comment: Why did you decide to reverse [W][H] and [H][W] respectively with:  int [][] pixels = new int [W][H];
int [][][] rgb = new int [3][H][W]; ?

Comment: I already changed it. but, I'm using 48x48 dimension image, so i think it doesn't matter with W and H position.